# Getting a Bivariate Polynomial From a Zero-Set

Tags: geometry, polynomials

Given the zero-set $\{x_0\}\subset\mathbb R$ of a function of the form$$ax+b,$$I can find one such function via$$f(x)=x-x_0;$$given the zero-set $\{x_0,x_1\}\subset\mathbb R$ of a function of the form$$ax^2+bx+c,$$ I can find one such function via$$f(x)=(x-x_0)(x-x_1)=x^2-(x_0+x_1)x+x_0x_1;$$and so on.

I am interested in the following problem:

Give the zero-set $Z\subset\mathbb R^2$ of a function of the form$$\sum_{i,j}c_{i,j}x^iy^j,$$where $i$ and $j$ are non-negative integers such that $i+j\leq n$, how can I use $Z$ in a way analogous to that above to find one such function?

References to relevant literature are appreciated since I am just getting into this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in general is difficult and belongs to the large field of *algebraic geometry*.  The situation is completely different in the case of two or more variables, since  the set of all zeroes $Z(p)$ of a polynomial $p$ in general is infinite. Let us for example look for a polynomial wich has $\xi=(a,b)$ as (one of its) zeroes. Then $q(x,y):=(x-a)(y-b)$ is a solution. But $Z(q)=\{(u,v)\mid u=a \text{ or } v=b\}$.